# Why is beautification essential for a sefer torah?

Tags: halacha, sefer-torah, maseches-gitin, hidur-mitzvah

The gemara in Gitin 54b declares worthless a Torah scroll that had all the Tetragrammatons rewritten because it ends up looking *menumar* (spotted), apparently because this would be a violation of "*ze eili v'anvehu* - the verse associated with the concept of beautification of mitzvot (*hidur*). My understanding is (was?) that *hiddur* is not *generally* necessary in order to fulfill the mitzvah. Why is this Torah then worthless?

Comment: Your question is based on your "understanding… that *hiddur* is not generally necessary in order to fulfill [a] mitzvah". What's that understanding based on?

Comment: Here's a [source](http://beinenu.com/sites/default/files/alonim/80_16_71.pdf) discussing when absence of *hiddur* (specifically *zeh eli ve'anvehu*) seems to be important enough to cancel the *mitzvah* (for example, Rashi explains that a dry *lulav* is *passul* for the same reason). Unfortunately I don't have time right now to sommarize it, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: @Cauthon The "four species" is likely not indicative of general rules, being that there is a special rule of (פרי עץ) הדר mentioned by them.

Comment: @DoubleAA Indeed he mentiones that in the left side of page 2 (some interpret "הדר" differently), but there are other examples as well.

Comment: @Cauthon I think doubleaa's logic is mentioned by Chassam Soffer in the beginning of lulav hagazul.

Comment: @msh210 e.g. at least one possible interpretation of "*hiddur mitzva ad shlish*" - that you're only obligated to upgrade if it's less than 1/3 more in cost to upgrade from the minimum of w/o *hiddur*. though i suppose that could be the wrong interpretation, and really it's just a shiur of how much *hiddur* is essential to fulfill the mitzvah... does seem to be a bit of a *chiddush* to say hiddur is *always* essential.

Comment: In a shiur I was listening to they distinguished between occasions in which *hiddur* is an addendum to the *mitzvah* (*talis naeh, tzitzis naeh*, etc.) and when it's an intrinsic requirement (the aforementioned *arba minim* is the most famous example). The *ksav Torah* apparently also requires *hiddur* instrinsically. The question is why *zeh eili* is a direct requirement here rather than an addendum.

Comment: @Loewian
May be if you formulate the question on basis of the Gemara 20A, the Ze Keli will be clearer. But I agree that in 54B we see the Machloket narrowed because Rabbi Yehuda agree in menumar and disqualifies the Sefer because The Keli ....

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an issue with *menumar* which is worse than regular Hiddur, unrelated to a Sefer Torah.

Look in [Suka 33a-b](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00883.html#HtmpReportNum0063_L2) that if there are lots of berries on your Hadas - and they are spread in 2 or 3 spots - then it's *menumar* and it's pasul because it's missing its hiddur.

So we see that *menumar* is almost the opposite of hiddur and makes it ugly - and hence Passul.

A similar thought is expressed in the [Chavrusa to Menachot 29b](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02367.html#HtmpReportNum0056_L2):

> אמר רב כהנא: משום דמיחזי שנראה הספר תורה כמנומר! כשכותב ומוסיף בין השיטין את מה שחיסר. אבל ביתירות **אין גרידת האותיות מכערת את הספר כל כך**, ואינו נראה כמנומר.‏

When you make it *menumar* it's a lot uglier than if you erase words or squeeze them between the lines.

Once something is that ugly, be it a Sefer Torah or a haddas, it's not fit for divine use.

Answer (score 2):

The Sde Tsufim in Gitin 20A has citted **Chidushey Hatam Sofer** in Gittin and in the Citted Gemoro succa 29B
I want to copy the text in hebrew and translate in english

דאפילו אם ואנוהו בשארי מצוות לאו דאורייתא, מכל מקום בכתיבת השם הוא דאורייתא כי כן משמע "זה קלי" השם הקדוש, "ואנוהו"

The litteral sense of the verse is bounded to the G-d, i.e. the Name of G-d. And the Tsivui is anvehu. 

There is a lot of difficulties in this subject but I think that this Hatham Sofer is a big novelty and answer the core of the question.
The **Rabeynu Krashkash** (in Chidushey Haritba Mossad Harav Kook, I, page 175) says a wonderfull thing, the expression Ein HaShem min Hamuvchar is a paraphrase of the verse Ze Keli veanvehu
And now disappear an other difficulty.
 Following the superficial reading, Eino min hamuvhar says that it is not mitsva min hamuvchar, but it is Kosher. How can Rav Chisda saying "Banu le machlokess" (so it is Passul)!?
Now, the following text of the Gemoro makes sense as a precise explanation of the term Eino min hamuvhar as a Psul of unaesthetic writing of the name of G-d!
**an important detail enabling to diminish the contrast between the opinion of** **Rabbi Yehuda and the Chachamim**
The Gemoro in daf 54B shows that The disagreement between Chachomim and Rabbi Yehudo no longer has to be held in case all the names were rewritten. So in menumar it is universally admitted that there is a psul of Ze Keli... (as Danny has added a further evidence from the Gemara Menachoss).

Comment: +1 (Btw, the passage is from the shirah al hayam  - Exodus 15:2)

Answer (score 1):

Rashi in Sukah 29b states that the requirement for hadar in arba minim comes from the passuk of zeh keili ve'anveihu.

Various rishonim (see tosafos there) ask on Rashi that zeh keili ve'anveihu is le'chatchilah, not be'dieved.

It seems from Rashi that when the absolute minimum expectation of hiddur is lost the din of zeh keili becomes an ikuv.

It is a 'dead' mitzva.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @pcoz
If I remember right, the topic of 4 Minim is different because we need "Hadar" "בשלמא יבש הדר בעינן וליכא "